# How to define AIX(alternate index) in CICS FCT entry?

Tags: aix, cics, vsam

What should the fct entry defining aix in vsam look like?

I searched online but couldn't find any explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to define a file is to use a FILE definition that is saved to the CICS CSD.  When defining a FILE you use the dataset name (DSNAME attribute) as the base, path or alternate index.

See the IBM docs for more details

https://www.ibm.com/docs/bg/cics-ts/5.3?topic=resources-file-attributes